# Plotting top values of a group on dc.js bar chart

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to plot only `top(n)` or `least(n)` values of a particular Crossfilter group in dc.js, but I'm not sure how to achieve this. I've checked it in `console.log()` that my group is returning values as needed, but how can I plot those top values in the chart?

```
groupForBandwidthConsumed = dimByOrgName.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
return d.bandwidthConsumed;
});
groupForBandwidthConsumed.top(Infinity).forEach(function (d) {
console.log(d.key, d.value);
});
```

I read that `.data()` function helps in doing this but it doesn't work with bar chart. Can somebody explain me how to do this?

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iSudeep/qafygso4/) for the bar chart I'm working on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I was able to sort it out myself using 'fake grouping' idea.

```
function getTops(source_group) {
return {
    all: function () {
        return source_group.top(2);
    }
};
}
var fakeGroup = getTops(groupForBandwidthConsumed);
```

Then modified the group attribute as: `.group(fakeGroup)`... [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iSudeep/0p78m8vr/)

Comment: With this, my problem is half solved. Because, I have to remove those empty blocks in the graph and arrange the bars in ascending order.

Comment: Right now the bar chart does not support [capping](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#cap-mixin), so this is the best you can do. Although there should be a more obvious syntax, I argue that pre-filtering is the right thing to do. To deal with arranging the bars in order, there is also `.ordering()`.

Comment: To get rid of the gap, simply don't supply the ordinal domain. It will be calculated automatically.