# Clearing empty positions and ordering dc.js bar chart

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I've used a fake group to fix my issue with plotting only top(n) values on a graph. Now I found an other issue that the bar chart shows a few empty positions for those data fields that doesn't come under 'ton(n)', I want to remove them and sort the bars in descending order of their values.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iSudeep/0p78m8vr/).

```
orgHigestBandwidthConsumed.dimension(dimByOrgName)
.group(fakeGroup)
.ordering(function (d) { return -d.value; })
```

I've tried `chart.ordering()` to order the bars which didn't work. Can somebody help me fixing this?

[image]

Comment: Ah, didn't see this other question. Will answer now!

Comment: link to previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30977987/plotting-top-values-of-a-group-on-dc-js-bar-chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are specifying the ordinal domain, dc.js will use that instead of calculating it using the existing values and the ordering you specify.

Simply remove the domain and specify the ordering:

```
.x(d3.scale.ordinal())
.ordering(function(kv) { return -kv.value; })
```

Fork of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0p78m8vr/6/

Comment: Sure, since you're doing the capping yourself, this should be easy - just change your fake group and ordering accordingly.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I've been trying to get the lower(n) values with no success. I'm trying to change the code in my 'fakeGroup'. May be I failed because I didn't find an alternative for `group.top()` in crossfilter library.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot there wasn't a `group.bottom()`! You'll need to have another group with the same key and reduce, but reverse it by specifying `.order(function(x) { return -x; })`. Then do your fake group with the same `.top(N)` on this other group.

Comment: That worked. All this time I was trying use `.order( )`, but didn't know that `return -x` gives reverse order. Thanks however.